# Laravel self updating event fires on creating

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel's built in event called "updating" to insert changes when a user performs an update. The problem I have is that the this event also fires when someone creates a post.

Here is the Model function I've made:

```
public static function boot()
{
    Product::updating(function($product)
    {
        $changes = [];
        foreach ($product->getDirty() as $key => $value) {
                $changes = [
                    'change' => $key,
                    'old'   => $product->original[$key],
                    'new' => $value
                ];
        }

        Log::create([
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'type' => "post_update",
            'log' => json_encode($changes)
        ]);
    });
}
```

How come event "updating" fires on creating also? How to prevent this? Thanks

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? This seems curious.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I am using version 5.3.

Comment: Just use something like this one https://github.com/shooka/laravel-modelevents.. it a bit more clean than having those events in the boot method

Comment: @jycr753 I've tried another solution by creating Events and firing them in the models boot method but still no luck, the updating still fires when creating. So the final solution I choose is firing the Event in the Controller when a update is made. Is this solution "good and clean"?